# Python Game Map

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
world_map = [['T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'K']]
x=0
y=0
def print_map(x,y,world_map):
    if world_map[y][x]=='':
        world_map[y][x]=='H'
    elif world_map[y][x]=='T':
        world_map[y][x]=='H/T'
    elif world_map[y][x]=='K':
        world_map[y][x]=='H/K'
    for i in world_map:
        print('\n'+'+---'*8+'+')
        for j in i:
            print('|{:^3}'.format(j),end='')           
    print('\n'+'+---'*8+'+')

print_map(x,y,world_map)
```

[image: outcome]

I have 2 questions,

1. How to get that last '|' on each row of the map?
2. why does the 'T' does not change to 'H/T' when my x=0 and y=0

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: How to get that last '|' on each row of the map?

You can do `print('|', end='')` after printing each row.

> Q2: why does the 'T' does not change to 'H/T' when my x=0 and y=0

You used a comparison operator `==`, not an assignment operator `=`.

---

You can try the following code:

```py
world_map = [['T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'K']]
x = 0
y = 0


def print_map(x, y, world_map):
    if world_map[y][x] == '':
        world_map[y][x] = 'H'
    elif world_map[y][x] == 'T':
        world_map[y][x] = 'H/T'
    elif world_map[y][x] == 'K':
        world_map[y][x] = 'H/K'
    for i in world_map:
        print('\n' + '+---' * 8 + '+')
        for j in i:
            print('|{:^3}'.format(j), end='')
        print('|', end='')
    print('\n' + '+---' * 8 + '+')


print_map(x, y, world_map)
```

which prints

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|H/T|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | T |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   | T |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | T |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   | T |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | K |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```